# Play: Conditional JSON creation

Tags: scala, playframework

Given the following code snippet...

```
val selector = if (condition == true)
  Json.obj("id" -> userId, "country" -> country)
else
  Json.obj("id" -> userId)
```

... is there a better – and more elegant – way to do the same?

Comment: It seems "fine" for the given example, silly explicit check on `== true` notwithstanding.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid repetition on the id part...

Comment: JSON combinators and `writeNullable` would be better, in my opinion, given that you're working in Play.

Comment: Yes, I'm working in play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the solution:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

val userWrites = (
  (__ \ 'id).write[String] ~
  (__ \ 'country).writeNullable[String]
).tupled

val json: JsValue = userWrites.writes(
  "1234",
  if (condition == true) Some("Germany") else None
)
```

I hope it helps.